# Highcharts Percentile Distribution Graph issue

Tags: javascript, excel, highcharts

can someone help me with the problem I have with the Highcharts graph below:

[My sample Percentile distribution graph Done with Highcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCmEI.png)

I'm trying to set up a percentile distribution graph with Highcharts but I have a problem with the horizontal axis that is not related to the data.

The goal is that my graph looks like this:
[Excel percentile distribution graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7QZ3.png)

For example, I have an Excel data table with two columns (DL_speed and Operator) and the Operator column contains 4 operators (Operator 1, Operator 2, Operator 3, Operator 4).
With Excel I have generated a pivot table that gives one column for DL_Speed and 4 columns for each operator whose values are in cumulative percentage (from 0% to 100%).
[Excel Pivot table with cumulative percent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XM0O.png)

The starting table is like this: [Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uGAb.png)

Here is an example of the code I wrote:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'line'
    },
    colors: [
      '#8b008b',
      '#1d98e0',
      '#ff8c00',
      '#f71d1d',
    ],
    title: {
      text: 'DL Throughtput Distribution (Mbps)',
      style: {
        color: 'Black',
        fontSize: '13px'
      }
    },

    subtitle: {
      style: {
        color: 'Black',
        fontSize: '11px'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 25000,
      tickInterval: 5000,
      minorTickInterval: 'auto',
      startOnTick: true,
      endOnTick: true

    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      tickInterval: 10,
      labels: {
        format: '{value}%'
      },
      title: {
        enabled: false
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
          this.x + ': ' + this.y;
      }
    },
    legend: {
      itemStyle: {
        fontSize: '11px'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'percent',
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Operator 1',
      data: [112, 207, 248, 356, 458, 555, 5690, 5890, 8220, 12500, 15690, 20000, 24000]
    }, {
      name: 'Operator 2',
      data: [100, 219, 411, 455, 545, 625, 7000, 9250, 11580, 14880, 19990, 22000]
    }, {
      name: 'Operator 3',
      data: [150, 228, 340, 469, 555, 569, 7030, 8990, 11990, 15690, 20010, 23200]
    }, {
      name: 'Operator 4',
      data: [109, 204, 232, 357, 428, 554, 6690, 7910, 932, 13000, 14990, 21000, 23000]
    }]
  }

  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that to enable the chart to display correctly,
you need to provide data that is properly formatted and understood by Highcharts.
Here you can find documentation on what data formats are allowed:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

If you have other data, you need to change it or format it first the way you want to display it.
Here you can see a simple example of parsing JSON data:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fsvrmd3u/

In your case, it will be necessary to specify the exact correct values for the X-axis and the percentages for the Y-axis: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s9pru70v/

```
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      format: '{value}%'
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [
      [0, 10],
      [1, 20],
      [2, 80]
    ]
  }]
```